# Is there a preferred way of including a Google results link in an SO question?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, google

In asking a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910212/where-is-rubys-erb-format-officially-defined) recently, I wanted to reference the results of a Google search so that others could easily click on it for themselves. I tried to use LMGTFY, but see that it's banned. I ended up using the link from the address bar after Google completed its search, but that contains all kinds of cruft specific to my environment.

Is there a simple/accepted/easy/tinyish alternative to LMGTFY?

Comment: I said I wanted to use it in a _question_, not an answer and have updated this question to include a reference to the question in which I used it.

Comment: ah, my mistake. Here is a google result for you: http://www.googleguide.com/linking.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the reference. If you want to post is as an answer, I'll upvote/accept it. Otherwise, I'll just add the link to Servy's answer, which I see you corrected.

Comment: LMGTFY is not a link resource; it is a snarky way to say RTFM.  That's why it is banned.

Comment: @TheGrinch I understand the snarky origin and typical usage and why it was banned. It has nice link generation capability, though, and figured in the context of asking a question, it wouldn't come across as snarky.

Comment: BTW Google search results are personalised somewhat so your top 4 may not be my top 4. Actually I see the question you just asked at number 3.

Comment: @MartinSmith Understand. :-)

Comment: Do you want this search to change with time? As google changes

Comment: @RichardTingle I assumed I had no choice in the matter. :-)

Comment: @peter that was my understanding, just wanted to check.  I'm just not sure how useful an ever changing reference is

Comment: @RichardTingle - Probably limited to those cases where one is generalizing about some characteristic one expects to be relatively persistent and or they just want to provide a ready means for someone to try the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [GoogleGuide.com](http://www.googleguide.com/linking.html) you link to a Google search result with:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=Google+tutorial+create+link
```

so you URL-encode the query and add is a the `q` parameter to the `http://www.google.com/search` URL.

[Demonstration link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+tutorial+create+link).

You could use an [online URL encoding tool](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) to create the query string for you. This is especially useful when trying to URL-encode non-ASCII search terms; `How to make a ☃?` becomes:

```
How+to+make+a+%E2%98%83%3F
```

when URL-encoded with UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

A link of the form `google.com/#q={search+query+goes+here}` will display the search results.

[example](https://www.google.com/#q=how+do+I+link+to+google+search+results)

Comment: This is the one I use.  If you want it shorter than that, you can use [this](http://goo.gl/).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do it

```
https://www.google.com/#q=enter%20your%20search%20terms%20here
```

or

```
https://www.google.com/#q=search+terms
```

you can also add

&start=10

if you want to start at a different point then the first results

Comment: I fail to see how your two examples differ, other than that they are searching for a different search term, and urlencode the space in two different but equally valid ways.

Comment: @Servy I was just showing that they can be entered in different ways and depending on how you enter them they can bring up different results. Using the first example I get different results when separated with %20 versus +. Both of those results where just copy and past from the search bar after searching so using what Google took my input as.